# Making a delimited text file for my data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am using QGIS 2.8 and I want to make a mesh file for dam break simulation. I am following a tutorial of BASEmesh for it. BASEmesh is QGIS plugin. My data is in form of dam dimensions, geometry and elevations.

Can anyone help me that how shall I create a delimited text file for it to put in delimited text layer?

Comment: We can't really help much without more information. Can you provide a sample of the data (first two lines including the column names if you have any as text formatted as code `{}` ) and anything you have tried and what results/errors you got.

Comment: Are you actually using the very old version 2.8, or is that a typo and you're using the very new version 3.8? Also please include a link to the tutorial.